# Unable to get memory map using e820

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management, operating-system, x86-16

I am writing a very basic kernel and for getting physical memory map, I used code from [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Getting_an_E820_Memory_Map)

```
global do_e820

do_e820:
    xor ebx, ebx        ; ebx must be 0 to start
    xor bp, bp      ; keep an entry count in bp
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; Place "SMAP" into edx
    mov eax, 0xe820
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   ; force a valid ACPI 3.X entry
    mov ecx, 24     ; ask for 24 bytes
    int 0x15
    jc short .failed    ; carry set on first call means "unsupported function"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; Some BIOSes apparently trash this register?
    cmp eax, edx        ; on success, eax must have been reset to "SMAP"
    jne short .failed
    test ebx, ebx       ; ebx = 0 implies list is only 1 entry long (worthless)
    je short .failed
    jmp short .jmpin
.e820lp:
    mov eax, 0xe820     ; eax, ecx get trashed on every int 0x15 call
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   ; force a valid ACPI 3.X entry
    mov ecx, 24     ; ask for 24 bytes again
    int 0x15
    jc short .e820f     ; carry set means "end of list already reached"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; repair potentially trashed register
.jmpin:
    jcxz .skipent       ; skip any 0 length entries
    cmp cl, 20      ; got a 24 byte ACPI 3.X response?
    jbe short .notext
    test byte [es:di + 20], 1   ; if so: is the "ignore this data" bit clear?
    je short .skipent
.notext:
    mov ecx, [es:di + 8]    ; get lower uint32_t of memory region length
    or ecx, [es:di + 12]    ; "or" it with upper uint32_t to test for zero
    jz .skipent     ; if length uint64_t is 0, skip entry
    inc bp          ; got a good entry: ++count, move to next storage spot
    add di, 24
.skipent:
    test ebx, ebx       ; if ebx resets to 0, list is complete
    jne short .e820lp
.e820f:
    extern memMapLength
    mov [memMapLength], bp  ; store the entry count
    clc         ; there is "jc" on end of list to this point, so the carry must be cleared
    jmp .done
.failed:
    ;stc            ; "function unsupported" error exit 
    hlt
    ret
.done:
```

And the C code is as follows:

```
uint8_t memMapLength=0;
uint64_t availableMemBytes=0;

typedef struct memoryMapEntry{
    uint32_t baseLow;
    uint32_t baseHigh;
    uint64_t length;   
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t acpi_null; 
    } memoryMapEntry;

memoryMapEntry* memMapArr=0; 
void DetectMem(){
    memMapArr= (memoryMapEntry*)(0x00007c40);
    uint8_t i;
    for(i=0;i<memMapLength;i++){
            if(memMapArr[i].type==1){           
                availableMemBytes += memMapArr[i].length;               
            }               
    }
}
```

In the kernel_main function, I call do_e820 function followed by DetectMem as follows:

```
do_e820();
DetectMem();
char *arr = (char *)&availableMemBytes;
terminal_write(arr);
```

However, I am not able to boot my kernel as the boot is getting stuck in an infinite loop. What mistake have I done?

Comment: where's [ES:DI] pointing to?

Comment: Hard to tell, because that's not an [mcve]. Also, learn to use a debugger, to at least pinpoint which part is getting stuck.

Comment: Can't you limit the use of assembly to the single call to the e820 service? Also, the assembly code is real-mode, the C code is too?

Comment: Also, you are invoking your asm code from C, but you don't seem to follow any calling convention, are you sure your compiler is happy with stuff such as zeroing `bp`? Following up to what Tommylee2k already asked, how is `es:di` even being set?

Comment: mov bx, 7c4h;mov es, bx;
mov di,0h;

Comment: It's unclear where you do that, certainly not in `do_e820` (as shown) so by that time it may very well be something else.

Comment: I have been doing it wrong. I am trying to use BIOS function in Protected mode whereas I should be in real mode. Can someone tell me if there is any memory map function that works in protected mode?

Comment: Protected-mode memory map can only be used on UEFI. On UEFI, this can be achieved using [the UEFI functions](https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Getting_an_UEFI_Memory_Map).

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWER USES INTEL ASSEMBLY.
You just removed a VERY IMPORTANT piece of code.

```
mov di, 0x8004
```

And instead of `jmp .done` use `ret`.
Remove the `.done` empty block.
Are you even using REAL MODE? For this reason, you should do this stuff in your Boot Loader.
Use `pusha` and `popa`.
Make it follow a calling convention. To make it follow one: `pop es`.
To get it to work, use this assembly:

```
    jmp kmain
do_e820:
    pop es
    pusha
    mov di, 0x8004
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor bp, bp
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150
    mov eax, 0xe820
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1
    mov ecx, 24
    int 0x15
    jc short .failed
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; Some BIOSes apparently trash this register?
    cmp eax, edx        ; on success, eax must have been reset to "SMAP"
    jne short .failed
    test ebx, ebx       ; ebx = 0 implies list is only 1 entry long (worthless)
    je short .failed
    jmp short .jmpin
.e820lp:
    mov eax, 0xe820     ; eax, ecx get trashed on every int 0x15 call
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   ; force a valid ACPI 3.X entry
    mov ecx, 24     ; ask for 24 bytes again
    int 0x15
    jc short .e820f     ; carry set means "end of list already reached"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; repair potentially trashed register
.jmpin:
    jcxz .skipent       ; skip any 0 length entries
    cmp cl, 20      ; got a 24 byte ACPI 3.X response?
    jbe short .notext
    test byte [es:di + 20], 1   ; if so: is the "ignore this data" bit clear?
    je short .skipent
.notext:
    mov ecx, [es:di + 8]    ; get lower uint32_t of memory region length
    or ecx, [es:di + 12]    ; "or" it with upper uint32_t to test for zero
    jz .skipent     ; if length uint64_t is 0, skip entry
    inc bp          ; got a good entry: ++count, move to next storage spot
    add di, 24
.skipent:
    test ebx, ebx       ; if ebx resets to 0, list is complete
    jne short .e820lp
.e820f:
    mov di, 0x8000
    mov [es:di], bp
    clc
    popa
    ret
.failed:
    stc
    popa
    ret
```

Replace `kmain` with your kernel main function name. Use NASM to output .o file (e820.o)